# How to link signal and slot when i change the font in the dialog

Tags: qt, qt5

This is how i am currently choosing the font in my application.

```
void FontChange()
{

    QString filePath = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(NULL, tr("Open File"),
        QStandardPaths::standardLocations(QStandardPaths::FontsLocation)[0],
        tr("Fonts (*.ttf);;Everything (*.*)"), nullptr,
        QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog);

    if (filePath.isEmpty())
        return;

    QlineEditSetFont->setText(filePath);
    stdstrLocation = filePath.toStdString();
    this->isChanged = true; // this executes the function
}
```

[image]

I want to execute a function whenever i change my selection in the Dialog , currently i  have to choose a font and than click on open to execute the function

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Now i am using a non modal way but how can i determine if cancel has been pressed.

Further Edit

```
QFileDialog* dialog = new QFileDialog();    
dialog->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
dialog->setNameFilter("TTF (*.ttf)");
dialog->setOption(QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog);
dialog->setDirectory("C:\\Windows\\Fonts"); 
QObject::connect(dialog, &QFileDialog::currentChanged, [=](const QString &path) {
        qDebug() << path; stdstrLocation = path.toStdString(); this->isChanged = true;
        QStringList fileNames = dialog->selectedFiles();
        qDebug() << "Selected FIles" << fileNames.size();
    });

    dialog->show();
```

Comment: You could make a `QFileDialog` instance, and connect [`QFileDialog::currentChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#currentChanged) signal to a slot.

Comment: @thuga i did but i cannot use the exec() function instead i use show() function.

Comment: and because of that i am not able to determine if cancel button is pressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the static convenience method but need to create the QFileDialog instance manually:

```
auto dialog = new QFileDialog(someParent);
dialog->setWindowTitle(tr("Open File"));
dialog->setDirectory(QStandardPaths::standardLocations(QStandardPaths::FontsLocation)[0]);
dialog->setNameFilter(tr("Fonts (*.ttf);;Everything (*.*)"));
// more setup...

connect(dialog, &QFileDialog::filesSelected, this, [this](const QStringList &selected) {
     // handle selection change here  
});

if (dialog->exec() == QDialog::Accepted) { // alternatively use open() to avoid blocking exec()
    // do something with dialog->selectedFiles()...
}

delete dialog;
```

Comment: i am using show function is it any way possible to determine  if cancel button has been pressed using Show() function.

Comment: if you don't want to call (blocking) exec(), call open() (instead of show()) and connect to the finished() signal (see https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#exec)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, those are two different questions. The one from the title has been already answered. The answer to the second one, namely **How can i determine if cancel has been pressed**, lies in the documentation of [`QFileDialog::getOpenFileName`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileName) itself:

> If the user presses Cancel, it returns a null string.

With this in mind, you can do something like:

```
void FontChange()
{    
    QString filePath = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(NULL, tr("Open File"),
        QStandardPaths::standardLocations(QStandardPaths::FontsLocation)[0],
        tr("Fonts (*.ttf);;Everything (*.*)"), nullptr,
        QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog);

    if (filePath.isNull()) {
        // user pressed Cancel
    } else if (filePath.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    } else {    
        QlineEditSetFont->setText(filePath);
        stdstrLocation = filePath.toStdString();
        this->isChanged = true; // this executes the function
    }
}
```

You can of course rewrite the `if` part to be more suitable to your app's logic.

As a side note, `QString::isEmpty` also implies that it is `NULL`.